# Align image and text in the middle of button element

Tags: html, css

What would be the best and easiest way to align text and image vertically in the middle of button. Example:

```css
button {
  padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
}
button img {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="http://latvijas-universitates-matematikas-un-informatikas-instituts.atver.lv/images/msn-icon.gif" alt="Text" />
  <span>Text</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button{
    padding: 5px 6px 5px 30px;
    background: url('http://latvijas-universitates-matematikas-un-informatikas-instituts.atver.lv/images/msn-icon.gif') no-repeat 5px center;
}
```

Comment: And what if there's a background image on the button from other styling? This is a strange workaround.

Comment: then he'd have to use something else...it's not really a workaround, since the image is part of the styling, I'd say that's preferable to an img tag. Plus you don't have to mess around with line-heights etc

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using image tags to display icons like this.

Answer (score 30):

While @paislee's solution *works*, it is not ideal. With the universal selector (`*`) being used, *every* element is checked against it (as CSS is matched right-to-left). A better solution, especially if all children elements are known, is to match the elements individually. Ergo, `button > img, button > span` is better than `button > *`.

```css
button {
  padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
}

/* Add this to align vertically */
button > img,
button > span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Text" />
  <span>Text</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This should have been the chosen solution for as it addresses the issue of accessibility. Users with visual impairments who rely on their browsers in Contrast Mode will not see the icon as all background images are removed. Anything that is contextual should be in an image tag.

Comment: Solution did not work for me, `<img>` still appears to align to bottom while `<span>` (or `<div>`, etc) appears to align middle in Firefox and Chrome.  Any updates for 2017?

Comment: @Steverino I've updated my answer with an image that actually loads, and it appears to work in Firefox and Chrome. Can you click "Run code snippet" above to see if it works for you? If it does, you may have an error in your personal code.

Answer (score 6):

Padding + img height = line height. Could play with the padding a little. Would be easier if img was odd number height as center is one pixel and eitherside is even number of pixels.

```
button{
    padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

button img{
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
        vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Could always scale the image down to 21x21 with CSS to make it an odd number. Shouldn't skew it that much.

Answer (score 4):

The following style vertically aligns every direct child of the button:

```
button > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/3uJKv/1/)

Comment: While this works, it uses the universal selector (*) and causes every element in the document to be checked against it (as CSS is matched right-to-left).

Answer (score 3):

Since we're positioning fixed-height content, we can use absolute positioning.

```
button{
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 30px;
    postion:relative;
}

button img{
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-11px;
}​
```

Adjust padding and left positioning to desired look.

Comment: This is overkill. `line-height` is sufficient for this.

Comment: Line height will break down if the button text runs long and wraps to the second line. I suppose it depends on how confident you are on what the text for the button will be in the future, but I'd prefer to do it this way now rather than deal with fixes later.

Comment: If the text wraps and your button height increases, you'll wind up with an image five pixels from the top left and not centered.

Comment: Good point. Updated for scalable vertical centering of image.